# WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() works only when the app is on foreground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to trigger a `WidgetKit` widget update with push notification.
In my understanding `.reloadAllTimelines` won't work if the user force-quited the app, but should work when the app is in background.

It looks like there's issue on Apple side - when updating iOS widgets with `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`, it works only when the main app is on foreground or debugging from Xcode.

Does anyone found a way to update these widgets? Any workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround for this problem in my experience.

As described in the [apple developer doc - Keeping a widget up to date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date), the `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` API is used to `reload the timelines for all your widgets`, but the refresh chance that every widget related to your main app has is always limited by the budget which is decided by the operating system using some kind of algorithm. You can find a description of the budget in the [apple developer doc - Plan reloads within a budget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date#Plan-reloads-within-a-budget).

If we really need a workaround for this, we can find some cases that are not limited by the budget in the same doc, they are:

```
Cases in which WidgetKit doesn’t count reloads against your widget’s budget include when:

- The widget’s containing app is in the foreground.
- The widget’s containing app has an active audio or navigation session.
- The widget performs an app intent, such as when the user taps a button or toggles a switch.
- The widget performs an animation.
- The system locale changes.
- Dynamic Type or Accessibility settings change.
```

For example, you can make your main app plays silent music all the time, and I think the `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` API will work all the time. But to say honestly, it does not make sense to do this kind of thing in an app.

In conclusion, the status of the main app matters. As if it is in the foreground, the refresh of the widget doesn't count reloads against your widget's budget. But in all other situations, whether the refresh happens or not is decided by the budget assigned by the operating system for the widget. As the daily budget typically includes from 40 to 70 refreshes, all we can do in a widget app is to set a refresh timeline that is within the limit and does not depend on `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reload when calling `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines` is not limited by the daily budget. I have submitted a TSI about widgets not updating when the app is in background. The response from Apple is: "We believe this issue is a bug. Please file a bug report via Feedback Assistant". However this issue is mentioned in some threads 3 years ago, so I'm not optimistic about being solved any soon. That's why I'm looking for a workaround. The silent music is not what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Stefo Do you have a link for that?

Comment: It definitely should work on background, the TSI Apple engineer also said so. About the budget - can’t find the source, probably my misunderstanding.